# Why JsonCreator does not work with JsonFormat shape OBJECT

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

This might have been covered in other StackOverflow topic, but I would like to know the reason why and how it works.

The code looks below:

```
@Document
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
@JsonAutoDetect()
public enum Compass {
    north("Upper Center"),
    south("Lower Center"),
    east("Left Center"),
    west("Right Center"),
    ne("Upper Right"),
    nw("Upper Left"),
    se("Lower Right"),
    sw("Lower Left"),
    ;

    @JsonProperty   
    private String presentableName;
    @JsonProperty   
    private String name;

    private Compass() {}
    private Compass(String presentableName) {
        this.presentableName = presentableName;
    }

    public String getPresentableName() {
        return presentableName;
    }
    public void setPresentableName(String presentableName) {
        this.presentableName = presentableName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Compass fromObject(@JsonProperty("name") String name) { 
       return Compass.sw;
    }
}
```

The Deserialization doesn't work with the above code.

nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `Compass` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('STRING'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Now if I use the below code with `@JsonCreator`, it works fine.

```
@JsonCreator
    public static TesterEnum fromObject(final Map<String, Object> obj) {
        if (obj != null && obj.containsKey("id")) {
            Integer id = null;
            if (obj.get("id") instanceof Integer) {
                id = (Integer)obj.get("id");
            } else {
                id = Integer.parseInt((String)obj.get("id"));
            }
            return fromId(id);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My questions are:

1. Why the second implementation works?
2. How the JsonCreator works? How does this get the values in the `fromObject` method parameter

Comment: Could you also show an example how you want to deserialise enum and what is the source `JSON`? Also, which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: @MichałZiober I want to deserialise the enum as OBJECT. The version of Jackson is 2.10.3
I want to send the json as a web response via a rest API.

Comment: I am not sure, I understand "enum as OBJECT.". Could you give me an example?

Comment: @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)

Comment: I noticed you use this annotation but it does not answer the question. How this enum is represented in `JSON` payload you want to deserialise? Cold you create an example with `JSON` payload and how do you deserialise it?